# @Published value not redrawing the view SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I have an observable class, where I have 4 @Published variables. The view is not redrawing when the @Published variables changing their value. I included my code to make it clear. The value in the viewModel is being changed because I can see how they are changing in the Debug console. What am I missing? 0

```
class CustomDrinkViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    
    //Quick drink menu  variables
    @Published var drinkOpacity: Double = 0 
    @Published var coffeeOpacity: Double = 0
    @Published var waterOpacity: Double = 0
    @Published var alcoholOpacity: Double = 0
    
    @ObservedObject var hydrationDocument = HydrationDocument()
    @Published var customDrinks: [CustomDrinkModel] = []
    var drinkArray: [CustomDrinkModel] = [] // Clone of the customDrinks from the above

//code for the Array where elements  it gets added and deleted 

 func getDrinkOpacity() {
        
        var waterOpacity: Double = 0
        var coffeeOpacity: Double = 0
        var alcoholOpacity: Double = 0
        var drinkOpacity: Double = 0
        

        for drink in drinksArray {
            if drink.isCustomWater {
                waterOpacity = 1
                drinkOpacity = 1
            } else if drink.isAlcohol {
                alcoholOpacity = 1
                drinkOpacity = 1
            } else if drink.isCaffeine {
                coffeeOpacity = 1
                drinkOpacity = 1
            } else {
                waterOpacity = 0
                alcoholOpacity = 0
                coffeeOpacity = 0
            }
            
            if waterOpacity == 0 && coffeeOpacity == 0 && alcoholOpacity == 0 {
                drinkOpacity = 0
            }
            
            self.waterOpacity = waterOpacity
            self.drinkOpacity = waterOpacity
            self.alcoholOpacity = alcoholOpacity
            self.coffeeOpacity = coffeeOpacity
        }
       
        print("water opacity \(self.waterOpacity)")
        print("coffee opacity \(self.coffeeOpacity)")
        print("alcohol opacity \(self.alcoholOpacity)")
        print("drink opacity \(self.drinkOpacity)")

        

    }

}
```

My View

```
[import SwiftUI

struct Dashboard: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var customDrinkDocument = CustomDrinkViewModel()
    
    // quick drink addition
    @State private var quickDrinkOpacity: Double = 1
    @State private var isQuickDrink: Bool = false
  
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            VStack {
                Text("water opacity \(customDrinkDocument.waterOpacity)")
                Text("drink opacity \(customDrinkDocument.drinkOpacity)")
            }
            Background(backgroundOpacity: $backgroundOpacity, isQuickDrink: $isQuickDrink, isFirstMenu: $isFirstMenu,customDrinkDocument: CustomDrinkViewModel())
                
                //            MARK: tool bar
                .toolbar(content: {
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
                        Spacer()
                        drop()
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .opacity(customDrinkDocument.drinkOpacity)
                            .scaleEffect(2)
                            .foregroundColor(waterColor)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                plus()
                            }
                            .padding()
                    }
                })
            
            
            
        }
        .onAppear{
            customDrinkDocument.getDrinkOpacity()
    
                
        }

//        .onChange(of: customDrinkDocument , perform: { value in
//            value.getDrinkOpacity
//        })
  
        
        .halfASheet(isPresented: $isDiuretic, content: {
            DiureticView(cups: $cups, waterColor: $waterColor, isCustomWater: $isCustomWater, isMetric: $isMetric, isDiuretic: $isDiuretic, popUp: $popUp, isAlcoholConsumed: $isAlcoholConsumed, amountOfAccumulatedAlcohol: $amountOfAccumulatedAlcohol, percentageOfEachAlcohol: $percentageOfEachAlcohol, amountOfEachAlcohol: $amountOfEachAlcohol)
                .environmentObject(CustomDrinkViewModel())
                .clearModalBackground()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
})


    }


    
    func plus(){
        withAnimation() {
            isQuickDrink.toggle()
            if isQuickDrink {
                backgroundOpacity = 0.6
                isFirstMenu = true
            } else {
                backgroundOpacity = 0.00
            }
        }
    }

    }
 

}][1]
```

my second view

```
import SwiftUI

struct DiureticView: View {
    
    @State private var customCoffeeName: String = ""
    @Binding var cups: Double
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @EnvironmentObject var customDrinkDocument: CustomDrinkViewModel
    @State private var scaleEffect: CGFloat = 1
    @State private var spacerAmount: CGFloat = 0
    @Binding var waterColor: Color
    @State private var editIndent: CGFloat = 0
    
    //Booleans
    @Binding var isCustomWater: Bool
    @Binding var isMetric:Bool
    @Binding var isDiuretic: Bool
    @State private var isEdit = false
    @State private var showCustomDrink: Bool = false
    @State private var isCustomDrink: Bool = false
    @State private var isAlcohol: Bool = false
    @Binding var popUp: Bool
    @State private var isCustomCoffee: Bool = false
    @State private var isCoffee: Bool = false
    
    //alcohol
    @Binding var isAlcoholConsumed:Bool
    @Binding var amountOfAccumulatedAlcohol: Double
    @Binding var percentageOfEachAlcohol: Double
    @Binding var amountOfEachAlcohol: Double
    
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                Color.gray.opacity(0.2)
                VisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: colorScheme == .dark ? .dark : .light))
            }
            VStack {
                if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
                    Spacer().frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height / spacerAmount, alignment: .center)
                }
                
                //MARK: Navigation of the diuretic view
                Spacer().frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 30)
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation() {
                            isCoffee = false
                            isAlcohol = false
                            isCustomDrink = false
                            showCustomDrink = false
                            isCustomWater = false
                            isEdit = false
                        }
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.backward")
                    })
                    .opacity(isCoffee || isAlcohol || isCustomDrink || isCustomWater || showCustomDrink ? 1 : 0)
                    .padding()
                    
                    Spacer().frame(width: geometry.size.width / spacerCaluclator())
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        customDrinkDocument.fetchFromServer()
                    }, label: {
                        if !isEdit {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise")
                            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90))
                        }
                    }).opacity(showCustomDrink || isCustomWater ? 1 : 0)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                            isEdit.toggle()
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "pencil")
                    }).opacity(showCustomDrink || isCustomWater ? 1 : 0)
                    
                    Spacer().frame(width: geometry.size.width / spacerCaluclator())
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        customDrinkDocument.getDrinkOpacity()
                        withAnimation() {
                            if isEdit {
                                isEdit = false
                            } else {
                                isDiuretic = false
                                isCustomWater = false
                                isCustomDrink = false
                            }
                        }
                    }, label: {
                        if isEdit {
                            Text("Done Editing")
                        } else {
                            Text("Done")
                        }
                    })
                    .padding(.horizontal, /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/10/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                }
                
                VStack {
                    if !isCoffee && !isAlcohol && !isCustomDrink && !showCustomDrink && !isCustomWater {
                        
                            VStack {
                                HStack {
                                    Image(colorScheme == .dark ? "waterDropDark" : "waterDrop")
                                        .renderingMode(.template)
                                        .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .white : .white)
                                }
                                .padding()
                                
                                Text ("Log a cup of Water")
                                    .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
                            }.onTapGesture {
                                cups += 1
                                isDiuretic = false
                            }
                            
                            VStack {
                                HStack{
                                    Image(colorScheme == .light ?  "coffee" : "coffeeDark")
                                        .renderingMode(.template)
                                        .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .white : .white)
                                }
                                .padding()
                                Text("Log Coffee")
                                    .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
                            }
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation() {
                                    isCustomDrink = false
                                    isAlcohol = false
                                    isCoffee = true
                                    print(isCoffee)
                                }
                            }
                            .opacity(!isCoffee || !isAlcohol || !isCustomDrink ? 1 : 0)
                            VStack {
                                HStack{
                                    Image(colorScheme == .light ?  "alcohol" : "alcoholDark")
                                        .renderingMode(.template)
                                        .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .white : .white)
                                }
                                .padding()
                                
                                Text("Log Alcohol")
                                    .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
                            }
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation() {
                                    isCustomDrink = false
                                    isCoffee = false
                                    isAlcohol = true
                                }
                            }
                            .opacity(!isCoffee || !isAlcohol || !isCustomDrink ? 1 : 0)
                            HStack {
                                Text("Log custom amount of water")
                                    .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
                            }
                            .padding()
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation {
                                    isCustomWater = true
                                }
                            }
                            HStack{
                                Text("Your custom drinks")
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
                            }
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation() {
                                    isCustomDrink = false
                                    isCoffee = false
                                    isAlcohol = false
                                    showCustomDrink = true
                                }
                            }
                            .padding()
                            
                            HStack {
                                Button(action: {
                                    isCustomDrink = true
                                    isCoffee = false
                                    isAlcohol = false
                                }, label: {
                                    Text("Add a custom drink")
                                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                                })
                            }
                            .padding()
                            
                        }
                    
                    //MARK: Coffee
                    if isCoffee  {
                        Text("Black coffee").padding()
                            .onTapGesture {
                                cups += 0.5
                                isDiuretic = false
                                popUp = false // close the popUp for the popUp view
                                print("black coffee \(cups)")
                            }
                            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
                        
                        Text("Decaf coffee").padding()
                            .onTapGesture {
                                cups += 0.95
                                isDiuretic = false
                                popUp = false // close the popUp for the popUp view
                                print("decaf coffee \(cups)")
                                
                            }
                            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
                        
                        Text("Starbucks coffees").padding()
                            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
                        
                        Text("Add custom coffee").padding()
                            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                isCustomDrink = true
                            }
                    }
                    //MARK: Alcohol
                    
                    if isAlcohol {
                        Text("Liquor 40%").padding()
                            .onTapGesture {
                                cups += 0.40
                                isDiuretic = false
                                popUp = false // close the popUp for the popUp view
                                print("liquor  \(cups)")
                            }
                            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
                        
                        Text("Wine 9%").padding()
                            .onTapGesture {
                                cups += 0.8
                                isDiuretic = false
                                popUp = false // close the popUp for the popUp view
                                print("wine 9%  \(cups)")
                            }
                            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
                        
                        Text("Beer 5%").padding()
                            .onTapGesture {
                                cups += 0.85
                                isDiuretic = false
                                popUp = false // close the popUp for the popUp view
                                print("wine Beer 5%  \(cups)")
                            }
                            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
                        
                        Text("Beer 4%").padding()
                            .onTapGesture {
                                cups += 0.9
                            }
                            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
                    }
                }
                
                //MARK: Custom Water
                if isCustomWater {
                    showCustomWater()
                        
                        .onAppear {
                            if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
                                editIndent = geometry.size.width  - geometry.size.width / 1.4
                            } else  {
                                editIndent = geometry.size.width  - geometry.size.width / 2
                            }
                        }
                } else {
                    showCustomDrinks()
                        .onAppear {
                            if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
                                editIndent = geometry.size.width  - geometry.size.width / 1.4
                            } else  {
                                editIndent = geometry.size.width  - geometry.size.width / 2
                            }
                        }
                }
                //                }
                //                //MARK: Custom Drink
                
                
            }
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 10)
        }
        .scaleEffect(scaleEffect)
        .onAppear {
            if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
                scaleEffect = 1.5
                spacerAmount = 5.8
                
            }
            print("Model name: \(UIDevice().type )")
            
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isCustomDrink, content: {
            CustomDrink(CustomDrinkDocument: CustomDrinkViewModel(), isMetric: $isMetric, isCustomDrinkSheet: $isCustomDrink, isDiureticSheet: $isDiuretic)
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $isCustomCoffee, content: {
            TextField("Name of the coffee", text:
                        $customCoffeeName)
        })
        Spacer()
    }
    
    func showCustomDrinks() -> some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack() {
                
                if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
                    Spacer().frame(width: 130)
                } else {
                    Spacer().frame(width: editIndent)
                }
                Text("Drinks: ")
                    .font(Font.body.bold())
                Text("Alcohol in gm: ")
                    .frame(width: editIndent)
                    .font(Font.body.bold())
            }.opacity(showCustomDrink ? 1 : 0)
            
            ForEach(customDrinkDocument.customDrinks, id: \.self) { drink in
                HStack() {
                    if drink.isAlcohol {
                        Image(colorScheme == .light ?  "alcohol" : "alcoholDark")
                            .renderingMode(.template)
                            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .white : .white)
                    } else if drink.isCaffeine {
                        Image(colorScheme == .light ?  "coffee" : "coffeeDark")
                    } else {
                        Image(colorScheme == .dark ? "waterDropDark" : "waterDrop")
                            .renderingMode(.template)
                            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .white : .white)
                    }
                    
                    Text(drink.name)
                        .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
                        .padding()
                        .onTapGesture {
                            cups += drink.amount
                            isDiuretic = false
                            popUp = false // close the .sheet and go back to the dashboard
                            if drink.isAlcohol {
                                isAlcoholConsumed = true
                                self.amountOfAccumulatedAlcohol += drink.alcoholAmount
                                percentageOfEachAlcohol  = drink.alcoholPercentage
                            }
                        }
                        .frame(width: editIndent)
                    
                    let formattedFloat = String(format: "%.1f", drink.alcoholAmount)
                    Text(formattedFloat)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        customDrinkDocument.deleteCustomDrink(customDrink: drink)
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
                    }).opacity(isEdit ? 1 : 0)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                }
                .onLongPressGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        isEdit = true
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }.opacity(showCustomDrink ? 1 : 0)
    }
    
    func showCustomWater() -> some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack() {
                
                if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
                    Spacer().frame(width: 150)
                } else {
//                    padding(.horizontal, 20)
                }
                Text("Name: ")
//                    .frame(width: editIndent)
                    .font(Font.body.bold())
                Text("Amount of cups: ")
                    .frame(width: editIndent)
                    .font(Font.body.bold())
            }.onAppear {
                print("editIndent: \(editIndent)")
            }
            
            
                ForEach(customDrinkDocument.customDrinks, id: \.self) { drink in
                    if drink.isCustomWater {
                        HStack() {

                            Image(colorScheme == .dark ? "waterDropDark" : "waterDrop")
                                .renderingMode(.template)
                                .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .white : .white)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    cups += drink.amount
                                    isDiuretic = false
                                    popUp = false // close the .sheet and go back to the dashboard
                                }
                                .padding()
                            
                            Text(drink.name)
                                .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
                                .padding()
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    cups += drink.amount
                                    isDiuretic = false
                                    popUp = false // close the .sheet and go back to the dashboard
                                }
                                .frame(width: editIndent)
                    
                            let formattedFloat = String(format: "%.1f", drink.amount)
                            Text(formattedFloat)
                            
                            Button(action: {
                                customDrinkDocument.deleteCustomDrink(customDrink: drink)
                            }, label: {
                                Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
                            }).opacity(isEdit ? 1 : 0)
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                        }
                        .onLongPressGesture {
                            withAnimation {
                                isEdit = true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.opacity(isCustomWater ? 1 : 0)
        }
        
    }
    
    func spacerCaluclator() -> CGFloat {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            return 4.3
        } else {
            return 5
        }
    }
}
```

The contents of the view not redrawn. However, in the ViewModel: the value of @published is being change here is the output from the Debug console:

```
 > water opacity 1.0 
> coffee opacity 0.0 
> alcohol opacity 0.0 
> drink opacity 1.0
```

Comment: Try `StateObject` instead of `ObservedObject`

Comment: @aheze I tried. I got the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you are using a number of separate CustomDrinkViewModel, and so a change in one does not relate to the others.

Although I cannot see where you actually change the customDrinkDocument,
try these modifications:

```
Background(backgroundOpacity: $backgroundOpacity, isQuickDrink: $isQuickDrink, 
isFirstMenu: $isFirstMenu,customDrinkDocument: customDrinkDocument) // <-- here

 DiureticView(cups: $cups, waterColor: $waterColor, isCustomWater: $isCustomWater, isMetric: $isMetric, isDiuretic: $isDiuretic, popUp: $popUp, isAlcoholConsumed: $isAlcoholConsumed, amountOfAccumulatedAlcohol: $amountOfAccumulatedAlcohol, percentageOfEachAlcohol: $percentageOfEachAlcohol, amountOfEachAlcohol: $amountOfEachAlcohol)
            .environmentObject(customDrinkDocument)  // <-- here
```

Comment: I tried it, it is showing if I add a drink. However, it is not reflecting when I removing an element from the @Published variable.

Comment: where in your code do you remove elements?

Comment: I updated my code. However, I could not add every part of my code since there was a character limitation.

Comment: There is a lot of code to take in, all I can say is look carefully at 
how you use and pass your "customDrinkDocument". You are passing yet another new 
CustomDrinkViewModel in the sheet in "DiureticView", use the one you have "customDrinkDocument" 

`CustomDrink(CustomDrinkDocument: customDrinkDocument, isMetric: $isMetric, 
  isCustomDrinkSheet: $isCustomDrink, isDiureticSheet: $isDiuretic)`

Comment: I didn't understand the difference between the @EnvironmentObject and @ObservedObject/@StateObject. I re-read the documentation and examined my code. Now everything works flawlessly. Thanks for your help.